# VBA Macro to operate on all workbooks in folder

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create a VBA Macro to open all workbooks and sheets in a certain folder and then copy and paste the information into the target sheet.

When I run my macro it gives me error 91 on targetWorkbook.

Could you help me out?

See code below:

```
Sub importTransData() Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

targetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Choose directory 
directory = "C:\Users\midijk\Desktop\Testsource\" fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""

Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook sourceSheet = ActiveSheet.Name sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'Select A2:F2

Range("A2:F2").Select

'Select everything below

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

'Copy Selection.Copy

'Select targetWorkbook 
Workbooks(targetWorkbook).Activate

'select targetsheet 
Sheets("Transactional Data").Select

'select A1 & go down 
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select

'Paste as values 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'go back to source workbook 
Workbooks(sourceWorkbook).Activate

'go back to source sheet 
Sheets(sourceSheet).Select

Next sheet

Workbooks(fileName).Close

fileName = Dir() Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: "C:\Users\midijk\Desktop\Testsource\" -  missing "\"

Comment: And once you put the missing "\" in, please move the `Loop` statement - or else you will be posting another question saying "why does Excel stop working when I run this code" (and the answer will be "because you have an infinite loop").  (I suspect you want the `Loop` immediately after the `fileName = Dir()` statement near the end of your code.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Main text updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys I found my solution!

```
Sub importTransData()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

'Choose directory
directory = "C:\Users\midijk\Desktop\Testsource\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""

Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet

Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

'Select A2:F2

Range("A2:F2").Select

'Select everything below

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

'Copy
Selection.Copy

'Select targetWorkbook
targetWorkbook.Activate

'select targetsheet
Sheets("Transactional Data").Select

'select A1 & go down
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select

'Paste as values
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'go back to source workbook
sourceWorkbook.Activate

'go back to source sheet
sourceSheet.Select

Next sheet

Workbooks(fileName).Close

fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```